# Jquery: Read or parse xml

Tags: jquery, xml

my xml look like this:

```
<Container>
<name>x</name>
<id>2</id>
</Container>
```

to be exact, this is view source of my xml result:
[image: xml result]

my jquery code:

```
 $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "somefile.jsp",
                        dataType: "xml",
                        success: function(xml) {


                            alert("123:"+xml+":321");


                            },
                        error: function(httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                        alert("status=" + textStatus + ",error=" + errorThrown);

                        }
                        });
```

**Question:** how do i read it from jquery and assign the name and id to variable? 
**Problem:** the alert return me xml document object

Comment: `var $xml = $(xml)` now use `$xml` as youu would a normal jQuery object

Comment: what about variable assignation of name and ID ?

Comment: var $xml = $(xml) does not work, still showing the object : xml document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `dataType` property in a `jQuery` causes the `success` callback to be called with an xml document. Now just wrap this with `jQuery`:

```
success: function(xml) {
    var $xml = $(xml);
    var name = $xml.find('name').text();
    var id = $xml.find('id').text();
    alert("123:"+ id + " " + name +":321"); //alerts "123: 2 x:321")
}
```

Comment: i added picture of my xml result in view source, there is empty line and newline with it.

Comment: @David thats fine just change `name` and `id` in my snippet to `act_type` and `process_id`

Answer (score 2):

Since the dataType is xml, the success callback gets a xml document as the result, in order to use jQuery to lookup elements you need to create a jQuery wrapper using `$(xml)` then you can use jQuery method on the new object as shown below

```
var $xml =  $(xml)
alert("123:"+$xml.find('name').text()+":321");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Z2A8X/)

Comment: @David see the fiddle

Comment: i added picture of my xml result in view source on my question, there is empty line and newline with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:  var container= $xml.find("Container").text();
if var container contains whole xml, then further you can find elements which you want.